# How do I turn off the automatic list feature in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode

I want to write a list like

```
1. bla
2. blabla
2.1 blabla
```

But having written `1.`, `org-mode` tries to infer what I want on the next line, which makes the numbering impossible to edit. How do I turn off this feature?

Comment: For the entire buffer, or just for one specific list?

Comment: I was thinking always, wherever. Workaround I am using now is to write `1,`, but looks ugly.

Comment: For me, I don't have a problem entering your example as Org-mode doesn't leap in and start numbering for me. I only get numbering when using M-ENTER, or "C-c C-c" on a list to re-number it. Have you rebound ENTER or set some other customisation up to be more aggressive in numbering?

Comment: Fudge, then this is due to some of my karabiner settings. I'm sorry! At least a great answer came out of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely understand what you're trying to do.  Here's your list:

```
1. item one
2. item two
2.1 subitem one
```

That's not how `org-mode` [plain lists](http://orgmode.org/manual/Plain-lists.html) work.  Each plain bullet can take an unordered character (`*`, `+`, or `-`), and ordered characters can be numbers (or single letters if `org-list-allow-alphabetical` is set to `t`), and the ordered characters end with either a `.` or a `)` (but you can set `org-plain-list-ordered-item-terminator` to allow *only* `.` or `)` if you like).

So, instead of what you've got, the list should look like the following, with `subitem one` demoted a level:

```
1. item one
2. item two
   1. subitem one
```

You can choose what form the demoted bullet takes by customizing `org-list-demote-modify-bullet`.  Let's say you want ordered (numbered) lists to start with `1.` and then demote to `1)` and then demote again to `1.`:

```
1. item one
   1) subitem one
      1. subsubitem one
2. item two
```

To achieve this, you could use the following:

```
(setq org-list-demote-modify-bullet '(("-"  . "+")
                                      ("+"  . "*")
                                      ("*"  . "-")
                                      ("1."  . "1)")
                                      ("1)"  . "1.")))
```

Again, if you plan to use text such as "2.1" within your bullet and don't want it to mess up your numbering, you can:

```
(setq org-plain-list-ordered-item-terminator ?\))
```

This will mean `org` will only allow order list bullets ending with parentheses, and will not recognize "2.", "2.1", etc., as bullets.